# After (def + -), is there any way to have + operator add instead of subtract?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure. To see if I could do something outlandish compared to Python, I did:

```
> (+ 2 2)
4
> (def + -)
#'sandbox6693/+
> (+ 2 2)
0
```

Which surprisingly worked, however I can't figure out how to get + to add  again after the definition above. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're removing the `clojure.core` function `+`, just *shadowing* it in your namespace.

You can get it back by redeffing `+` to be the function in `clojure.core` by referencing it including the namespace:

```
user=> (def + -)
#'user/+
user=> (+ 2 2)
0
user=> (def + clojure.core/+)
#'user/+
user=> (+ 2 2)
4
```

But.... why?!

Answer (score 2):

As @Russell said, you're just shadowing the `clojure.core/+` with `user/+`.

What would i do for experimenting with clojure, is to just establish some local binding (again shadowing the core `+` with your `+`, but keeping the changes inside the binding scope, not to make a mess):

```
user> (let [+ -]
        (+ 1 2 3))
-4

user> (+ 1 2 3)
6
```

But in general there are special ways to do what you want (to change the value of the var, execute some code in the scope where the var is changed, and then automatically restore it's value):

first one is to use `binding` (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) the problem is it only works for special `dynamic` vars, so it's not really applicable in your case, since `+` is not dynamic

the second one, is to use `with-redefs` (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs) which is closer to what you need, but there is one problem there:

```
user> (with-redefs [+ -]
        (+ 1))
-1 ;; as expected

user> (with-redefs [+ -]
        (+ 1 2 3))
6 ;; unexpected!
```

the second example fails, because the compiler inlines `+` function, when there are more than one arg passed to it and replaces it with `add` function call)

Also, for some purely educational purpose you can make a macro, that would generally redefine everything you need, saving the old value, and restoring it after block evaluation:

```
user> (defmacro redefine [old new & body]
        `(let [v# ~old]
           (def ~old ~new)
           (let [res# (do ~@body)]
             (def ~old v#)
             res#)))
#'user/redefine

user> (redefine
       + -
       (+ 1 2 3))
-4

user> (+ 1 2 3)
6

user> #'+
#'user/+

user> (redefine
       + *
       (+ 1 2 4))
8

user> (redefine
       + *
       (+ 1 2 4))
8

user> (+ 1 2 4)
7
```

Comment: That's an interesting gotcha with the compiler inlining of the add function!

Comment: Although this is a great answer, I would strongly advise you to avoid macros for as long as possible if you're new to Clojure, @Atonal...  there are very few cases where they are required, but using them incurs a not insignificant cost in terms of code understandability, and they are often overused by beginner/intermediates.

Comment: @Russell i agree, that macros add some complexity, and sometimes quite hard to understand, especially for the beginner, but on the other hand, it is an fantastically powerfull instrumentation, which makes lisps stand out a mile, so i would just say "use responsively" instead of "avoid" )